# window.open with popup blocker

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to open a certain page from my default page.
All the code there is in the default page is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.open("StartPage.aspx", "", "fullscreen=yes");  
</script>
```

The problem is that the browser's popup blocker blocks this and I need allow the browser to open it.
I want to avoid this and that every one that will use my web application won't need to allow the popup blocker to open the page. I want to pass the popup blocker and open the page without  permission.

Is there a way to do so?
Thanks

Comment: If you could bypass a popup blocker, don't you think all the ad spam would be doing it?

Comment: If you could bypass the popup blocker, it wouldn't be a popup blocker.

Answer (score 13):

adamantium is right. a popup blocker would be pretty useless if it could be overridden by the code that's causing the popup. the best you can do is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myPopup = window.open("StartPage.aspx", "", "fullscreen=yes");  
    if(!myPopup)
        alert('a popup was blocked. please make an exception for this site in your popup blocker and try again');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, you simply can't. The browser is blocking that behavior. Another option would be to not use `window.open` but instead use a javascript component which can give you the same behavior.

Comment: It seems that he does not want a "popup", but rather open the page in fullscreen.

Comment: Correct, but that won't be possible so I have given an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do that. Its a user preference to block pop up windows and you have no control over that.

Answer (score 1):

You can open popup using onclick event only. You can try submitting form with `target="_blank"` and action set to your url, but forefox blocked this, google chrome not.

Comment: Piotr M. is right! that's the ONLY thing that will work! No wonder I was having my popups blocked this whole time, I had them triggered through the onmousedown event, who would've known it would behave differently! Thanks Piotr!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's impossible, everyday I see streaming pages opening popups all the time and mine's being blocked so it should be a way to bypass it

Answer (score 0):

You have to fire the function from an user event such as onclick().

```
const anchorElement = document.querySelector('a');

anchorElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.open("StartPage.aspx", "", "fullscreen=yes");
});
```