# PopUp Blocker verify

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

How can I Check if the client Browser has a popup blocker turned on via C# ?

I tried to open an popup like this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "newWindow", String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}', 'Cliente', 'toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no, scrollbars=yes,resizable=no', '720', '600', 'true'); </script>", url));
```

But i need to open a Alert if the browser have a popup blocker

How can I do that ?

Comment: So you want to fix a blocked popup with another popup?  Perhaps the user doesn't want any popups.

Comment: @JaredPar alert windows are not blocked by pop-up blockers.

Comment: I want open a popup. If the browser has the PopUp Blocker turned on, I just sent a Alert Message

Comment: I'd help but pop-ups are horrible. Also as C# is server-side I don't think it will be giving you much information on the client's browser.

Comment: @Icarus yes I realize they're not blocked by pop-up blockers. They still do "pop-up" though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "newWindow", String.Format("<script>var myPopup = window.open('{0}', 'Cliente','toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no, scrollbars=yes,resizable=no','720', '600', 'true');if(!myPopup)alert('a popup was blocked. please make an exception for this site in your popup blocker and try again');</script>",url));
```

**Note**:  Did not test whether it compiles or not, but that's the general idea.

[See this other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790035/window-open-with-popup-blocker)

**EDIT -** adding test:

```
string mys="<script>var myPopup = window.open('{0}', 'Cliente','toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no, scrollbars=yes,resizable=no','720', '600', 'true');if(!myPopup)alert('a popup was blocked. please make an exception for this site in your popup blocker and try again');</script>";

Console.WriteLine(string.Format(mys,"page.aspx"));
```

Produces:

```
<script>var myPopup = window.open('page.aspx', 'Cliente','toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no, scrollbars=yes,resizable=no','720', '600', 'true');if(!myPopup)alert('a popup was blocked. please make an exception for this site in your popup blocker and try again');</script>
```

I don't see anything wrong with that. Now, my suggestion is that you remove the `<script></script>` tags and let RegisterStarupScript add them by passing `true` as the last parameter as so:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "newWindow", String.Format("var myPopup = window.open('{0}', 'Cliente','toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no, scrollbars=yes,resizable=no','720', '600', 'true');if(!myPopup)alert('a popup was blocked. please make an exception for this site in your popup blocker and try again');",url),true);
```

Comment: @Lucas_Santos you need to be more specific. `Invalid Format` where? when you compile?

Comment: No, the application compiles and build without errors. But when will open the PopUp, the error System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. In the ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript line

Comment: Excelent!! It works removing the <script></script> like you said! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I guess all modern browsers would block popups which are not triggered by an action of the user, eg. clicking on something. Do you really need the roundtrip to the server before opening the window?

If the roundtrip is not necessary, you should do something like:

```
<input type="button" onclick="openWindow()" value="open window" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openWindow() {
        window.open('<%= Url %>', 'Cliente', 'toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no, scrollbars=yes,resizable=no', '720', '600', 'true');
    }
</script>
```