# How To redirect a webpage to Multiple domains/urls in Wordpress

Tags: redirect, wordpress

How can i redirect my page to multiple urls.

Example : if my webpage is http://www.mynewurl.com/test

I want to redirect the above the page to

1. google.com
2. yahoo.com

These two pages should open in two different tabs in a window if I open this page http://www.mynewurl.com/test

How can I achieve this in Wordpress, Is there any plugin to do so.

Any help would be wonderful.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect in PHP but this would only allow you to redirect to one URL, e.g.:
`<?php header('Location:http://www.google.com');?>`

You could do it in javascript by doing:

`<script type="text/javascript">
window.open('http://www.google.com');
window.open('http://www.yahoo.com');
</script>`

Of course, this will be blocked by most browser popup blockers.  One way to handle it is here: [window.open with popup blocker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790035/window-open-with-popup-blocker)

See here for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

If you want that javascript to run when you access a particular page in Wordpress then you need to make a new template and set the template for a page to it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates