# Javascript to disable popup blocker

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript i want to know pop up blockers is disabled or not. If Enabled i want for users to throw an message saying that to Disable the pop up and if user accepts to disable the pop up it will allow user to proceed further if not, User will be on the same page. Please help me with the code so that it will run in all the browser(IE, Mozilla, Chrome n safari)

Comment: show some code have you tried?

Comment: Open up a window and see if you can access the window or not.

Comment: cript type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var PopupWarning = {
            init: function() {
                var pop = window.open('about:blank', 'new_window_123', 'height=150,width=150');

setTimeout(function() {
if(!pop || pop.closed || pop.closed == 'undefined' || pop == 'undefined' || parseInt(pop.innerWidth) == 0 || pop.document.documentElement.clientWidth != 150 || pop.document.documentElement.clientHeight != 150){
pop && pop.close();
alert('Popups must be enabled.');
}else{
alert('Popups is enabled.');
pop && pop.close();
}}, 1000);

Comment: Please put the code in your post, not a comment.

Comment: Can anyone please help me? the code should work only if user accepts to block pop up, if not, user will be on the same page

Comment: Also please make sure you've researched this question properly; I found [an answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1790121/2245528) from the "related questions" sidebar. Didn't even take me a minute.

Comment: @computerfreaker: Can you please let me know that piece of code or link?

Comment: I put the link in my last comment. Here it is again: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1790121/2245528

Comment: @computerfreaker: it was not close to my solution. thanks for letting me know:) my question is to check pop up blockers is enabled if yes, user have to disable it if not, user will be on the same page

Comment: @user3044594 Yes, but the answer I linked is more or less what you're looking for. It tries to show a popup window and if the window can't open (in other words, if a popup blocker is present and enabled) it shows an error message. The user _does_ stay on the same page. Francois Borgies' answer is the same thing.

Comment: @computerfreaker:Great:) you mean user will be allowed to proceed further only for the person who have disabled pop up. If yes, can you send me the complete code to my personal mail ID i,e girishsmiley@gmail.com Appreciate your quick response:) thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

It is there to stop them and you can not turn it off. Best you can do is:

```
winpop = window.open("asdf.html");
if(!winpop || winpop.closed)alert("foobar");
```